# Образ и образец

Tags: морфемика

Являются ли родственными словами "образ" и "образец", можно ли выделять и в том, и в другом случае корень "образ"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что Тихонов считает эти слова не однокоренными (образец - корень **"образец"**, образ - корень **"образ"**), я склонен считать их таковыми, т.к. связь между предметами действительности не утрачена. **Образец** - *это то, что дает определенный образ.*

---

"Школьный словарь строения слов русского языка" под авторством З. Потихи считает именно так: слова "образ" и "образец" имеют один общий корень - **образ**.